How far has a national team gone in an international tournament without scoring a goal in the open play?
France has made it to the semi finals of the Euro 2024 having only scored 3 goals. 2 of those were own goals scored by the opposition, and the other was a penalty kick scored by Mbappe. It's hard to believe, but the French team which were the favourite prior to the star of the tournament, has made it to final 4 without having scored a goal credited to their own players during open play.
What's the furthest a national team has made it in an international tournament (World cup, continental cups) without scoring a goal in the open play?
Competitions have had fewer rounds and different formats throughout the years. So please include the number of matches played and minimum number of matches a team was guaranteed given the format (ex, in Euro 2024 each team was guaranteed 3 games).
